# Sending a file from local to server using python - the correct way

Tags: python, sockets

Probably a simple question for those who used to play with `socket` module. But I didn't get to understand so far why I can't send a simple file.

As far as I know there are four important steps when we send an info over a socket:

- open a socket
- bind
- listen
- accept ( possibly needed multiple times ).

Now, what I want to do is creating a file on my local machine and fill it with some info. ( been there, done that - all good so far )

Then, I create my client flow, which is the following:

```
s = socket.socket() # create a socket
s.connect(("localhost", 8081)) # trying to connect to connect over 8081 port

f = open("logs.txt", "rb+") # I'm opening the file that contains what I want
l = f.read(1024) # I'm reading that file

# I'm sending all the info from the file
while l:
    s.send(l)
    l = f.read(1024)
s.close()
```

Of course, firstly, I'm creating a server (at first, on my localhost) which will open that port and basically create the connection which will allow the byte-chunked data to be sent.

```
import socket
import sys

s = socket.socket() # create the socket
s.bind(("localhost", 8081)) # bind
s.listen(10)

while True:
    sc, address = s.accept()
    print sc, address
    f = open('logs_1.txt', 'wb+') # trying to open a new file on the server ( which in this case is also my localhost )
    while True: # write all the data to the file and close everything
        l = sc.recv(1024)
        f.write(l)
        l = sc.recv(1024)
        while l:
            f.write(l)
            l = sc.recv(1024)
    f.close()
    sc.close()
s.close()
```

Now, what doesn't work on my Ubuntu 14.10 machine:

- the server part runs without error when doing `python server.py`
- after the client script finishes writing some data in `logs.txt` and  connects to the server, I get the following response on the server:

  ```
  <socket._socketobject object at 0x7fcdb3cf4750> ('127.0.0.1', 56821)
  ```

What am I doing wrong ? The port is also different from the one that I set ( I also know that the port is not used - verifiet with `nc` ).

Can anybody explain me how to correctly treat this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your second `while True` loop is for. Remove that, and it works as you expect:

```
import socket
import sys

s = socket.socket() # create the socket
s.bind(("localhost", 8081)) # bind
s.listen(10)

while True:
    sc, address = s.accept()
    print sc, address
    f = open('logs_1.txt', 'wb+')
    l = sc.recv(1024)
    while l:
        f.write(l)
        l = sc.recv(1024)
    f.close()
    sc.close()
s.close()
```

Comment: I got the same result. I'm also wondering why the chosen port is not used. Instead of the port I want, another random one is used

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what your problem is then? The port isn't a problem. The port that is printed is the source port, the one the client chooses to connect *from*. That will always be different, and somewhere between 1024 and 65535. With my code above, `logs_1.txt` gets populated with the data from `logs.txt`, so works.

Comment: Thank you Ben. Your answer saved my assignment :)