# How to receive data in chunks in python socket

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to receive a file in python. I'm able to receive file as a whole with the below code.

```
try:
    while(recv_data):
        file.write(recv_data)
        sock.settimeout(2)
        recv_data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)
except socket.timeout:
    file.close()
```

I have 2 queries which I need help.
1) How will I receive data in chunks instead of full data
2)Suppose I have a file larger than 65K how can I receive a file.

At the sender side my code:

```
try:
    socket.sendto(file,(ip, port))
except (socket.error):
    print("error")
```

Can you please let me know the changes I should do at sender and receiver so that I should send and receive in chunks of 512 bytes.?

Comment: Edit: I don't want to use any additional packages.

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Check out this question/answer, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33284158/57158